# Is the toilet in the "Shared Cell" just not enough for the prisoners is contains?

Tags: prison-architect

I thought I would try out the Quick Build, "Shared Cell". This is a dormitory with 2 bunk beds and 1 toilet. I polished it up with a Bookcase, TV, radio, shower/drain, window, payphone, and a chair.

I then cloned it 12 times, to form the bulk of my "minimum security" prison's accommodations. These are, more or less, the only toilets in my prion. (There is also one in the holding cell, but that is it).

Now, it seems like my prisoners constantly need to go to the toilet. The Bladder speech bubble keeps showing. For example, when they are in the chapel, or doing Education, more or less all the time.

I am wondering if the one toilet between four prisoners is just not enough and if maybe this is contributing to my daily stabbings.

Almost all there regime is set to *Work/Free time* -- which I assume means they will go back to their shared cell at this time to use the toilet.

Comment: I've read around that during work time, they won't use the bathroom when they need to for some reason. I'm wondering if that's the issue.

Comment: @TimmyJim I think it was. I tool away an hour of sleep before breakfast/shower for to FreeTime, and now, no more breakfast stabbings.

Answer (score 3):

I put toilets all over the place in my prisons:

- yard - they don't mind going to toilet outside
- showers - while waiting for a free shower they use them (phones and weight benches are useful in the shower as well)
- canteen - gross, yes, but they use them!

If you are having "daily stabbings" then you probably want to add some more toilets.

Comment: I've done this as well - I have toilets in just about every room in my prison. Canteens (I don't let inmates in the kitchen -- too many weapons smuggled out) chapel, mailroom, shower, workshop, holding cell, reception, etc.  This has drastically reduced the prison stabbings for me, I'd highly recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Prisoners try to meet their needs with a few restrictions:

- During specific periods, they will not leave the area that activity is in. During shower time, prisoners will not leave the "shower" areas in your prison, during "eat" time, prisoners will not leave the canteen areas in your prison, etc.
- When the prisoner has something better to do, such as classes, work or rehab programs, they will go there instead. The prisoner is then confined to their activity area again (e.g. classroom, shop, workshop). They will use items there.
- When items are not in a zoned room, prisoners just tend to ignore them. Completely.
- When prisoners have gang business, they will go there instead of meeting needs.

When your toilets are only in cells, keep in mind that a prisoner will only use the toilet in the cell they are currently assigned to. The travel time is potentially quite big. The prisoner might just not arrive in time.

---

In any case, building anything realistic will prove difficult. The game has trouble when you have doors in a zoned area. As long as a toilet is in a zoned area, and the prisoner is allowed/supposed to be in that area, they will use that toilet to meet their needs.

Building a high-capacity high-risk prison usually involves having items in unusual places, so prisoners can meet their needs with as little downtime (walking) as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try freeing up the prisoners schedule. As I said in my comment, [I've read that during work hours, they will not use the bathroom](https://steamcommunity.com/app/233450/discussions/0/357287935556874199/) for some reason. In your question, you said that almost all their time is for work and then free time, but while they are working, their bladders will not be relieved.

Comment: This is exactly why I use the last hour of "sleep" as "Free Time" in my regime. That way they aren't shanking other inmates in the canteen because they have to pee so bad. Plus the janitors love the change too, less urine and feces to clean up.